# Why do I get Access Denied on refresh when deploying Angular app with Amplify?

Tags: angularjs, aws-amplify

technical questionAccess Denied on refresh using Amplify (self.aws)

submitted 26 minutes ago by ParkerZA

So I'm using Amplify to host an Angular web app. When doing so you are supposed to set up your rewrites and redirects like this:

```
[
    {
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?! 
(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

Which worked for a bit. But ever since we've upgraded to Angular 11, this has stopped working, and the app just hangs now, without even loading. Really not sure if this is an Angular or AWS problem but would appreciate any help.

Comment: One doesn't simply upgrade to Angular 11/12 ...without rewriting some parts of the app, if not the whole app.

Comment: @MartinZeitler the app itself works perfectly, it's just this issue we seem to be having. I can't for the life of me figure out what's different between the two to cause this issue either.